# Shipping methods not showing

Tags: magento2, product, shipping, javascript, catalog

During checkout, I get a long list of "€0" for my shipping methods:
[image: shipping methods]

However, in the admin panel, I enabled only the fixed shipment option and set it to €5 per order.

I'm using Magento 2.0.8.

Nothing happens when I click the "next" button to proceed to payment.

I have no JS errors, neither I find errors in var/reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check our answer to your question [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Checkout-Summary-shows-undefined-undefined-shipping-before/m-p/29722#M460):

I'll copy-page the massage just in a case:

> If after entering address details your checkout looks somewhat like
>   this:
>
> [image]
>
> ... most likely the reason why the issue occurs is because your
>   service doesn't provide the correct response to the
>   estimate-shipping-methods query.
>
> You can check what the server response in the browser console:
>
> [image]
>
> The inability of Magento 2 to process cases with invalid JSON in a
>   server response makes the script put a high load on the browser (it
>   just gets in a loop). Plus, the script creates a big amount of
>   "s_method_undefined_undefined" methods ("undefined" means that when
>   sending a query, no response was received, since the object is empty).
>
> In most cases, the issue was caused by the absence of these php.ini
>   settings:
>
> ```
> date.timezone = America/New_York
> always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
> ```
>
> Right after you add them, the checkout should start working as
>   expected.
>
> [image]
>
> Most likely, a similar issue can occur because of other missing php
>   settings -- they can trigger errors when executing the code.
>
> Also, most likely, disabling error display (magento deploy:mode:set
>   production) will let you avoid such behaviour at the checkout step.

Answer (score 0):

proposal : check for promotions for this error.

Magento ver. 2.2.5 admin panel.
"Marketing > Promotions > Cart Price Rulse"

you can get the error if the cargo is to be in cart price rules.